# how to execute several ddl words with batch processing

Tags: oracle, ddl

When I deploy my asp.net application,I have to create some tablesapces/users,I use the pqsql,however I want to know is there any way I can create them with batch processing?

For example,I can execute this ddl:

```
create tablespace TSA.....
```

Then I can execute:

```
create user a ... default tablespace TSA...
```

But when I execute them at the same time:

```
create tablespace TSA.....

create user a ... default tablespace TSA...
```

I will get an error.

ANy way?

**update**

Error is something like this:

```
ORA-02180: invalid CREATE TABLESPACE words
```

BTW,I run the sql batches in the sql window of the pl/sql developer.

Now,I just want to know if there is any way I can run a whole ddl sql file?

Suppose this is the content of the `init.sql`:

```
create smallfile tablespace "DEV" datafile 'f:\app\administrator\oradata\orcl\dev01.dbf' size 100m autoextend on next 10m maxsize unlimited logging extent management local segment space management auto default nocompress


-- Create the user 
create user dev_sa
  identified by "000000"
  default tablespace DEV
  temporary tablespace TEMP;
-- Grant/Revoke role privileges 
grant connect to dev_sa;
grant dba to dev_sa;

--create another tablespace
--.....
```

How to execute it in the batch process model?

Comment: What error do you get?  Oracle has tens of thousands of error messages, any number of which might apply here.  Unfortunately we are not telepathic, so we need you to give us more information.  Also, it will help if you show us the whole code.  If it's a syntax error we won't be able to help you unless we see the entire script.  Finally, how are you running these statements? SQL*Plus? An IDE liek TOAD or SQL Developer?  Shell scrupts?

Comment: What exactly is "pqsql"? I have never heard of such a tool in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the two statements in a file you're running from SQL*Plus, you need to separate the statements with the `/` character, which also causes each to be executed

```
create tablespace TSA ...
/

create user a ... default tablespace TSA
/
```

(That's quite a big 'if', of course as per @APC's comment; but is something that's come up before. As has different ways of running things in SQL Developer, among other things. But really no more than a guess from the minimal info given...)

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon `;` missing off the end of your first `CREATE TABLE`